# Enhance Vegetation Index ( EVI ) equation in ENVI IDL

Tags: envi

I'm using ENVI 5.3 to find EVI, when I'm applying the equation it doesn't run, anybody can provide me the exact equation or formula for running the index. For more clarification, I'm using Landsat 8 OLI.